# How to make the search box remain blue even after mouseout?

Tags: jquery

I wrote a script to make the search box in question have a default border color, hover border color and clicked border color. Is there a way  could augment this code to make it to where even if you mouseover or mouseout after you've clicked in the search box, the border remains blue?

```
var searchBar = $(".qstxtcommon");

$(searchBar).on("mouseover", function() {
  $(searchBar).css("border-color", "#666666")
});

$(searchBar).on("mouseout", function() {
  $(searchBar).css("border-color", "#b7b7b7")
});

$(searchBar).on( "click", function() {
  $(searchBar).css("border-color", "#3fa9f5");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because after click, `mouseout / mouseover` still works... try that

```
$(searchBar).on( "click", function() {
  $(searchBar).css("border-color", "#3fa9f5");
  $(searchBar).on("mouseout",null);
  $(searchBar).on("mouseover",null);
});
```

or

```
$(searchBar).on( "click", function() {
   $(searchBar).css("border-color", "#3fa9f5");
   $(searchBar).off("mouseout");
   $(searchBar).off("mouseover");
});
```

Comment: Don't you have to unbind 'mouseover' too?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use a semaphore

```
var searchBar = $(".qstxtcommon");
var clicked = false;

$(searchBar).on("mouseover", function() {
  if (!clicked) {
    $(searchBar).css("border-color", "#666666");
  }
});

$(searchBar).on("mouseout", function() {
  if (!clicked) {
    $(searchBar).css("border-color", "#b7b7b7");
  }
});

$(searchBar).on( "click", function() {
  clicked = true;
  $(searchBar).css("border-color", "#3fa9f5");
});
```